# Creating buttons with commands meant to be dynamic but is assigning each button command's argument to the last index of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What this is meant to do is pack buttons to root, with each button having a different text and argument being passed in from the 'boards' list in the loop. I have tried using 'in range', accessing that element in that loop but didn't work either.

```
def BoardSelect():
    Clear()
    boards = getBoards()
    for board in boards:
        Button(root, **config, bg="dark gray", text=board, command=lambda:PresetSelect(board)).pack(fill="x", pady=2)
    Button(root, **config, bg="dark gray", text="All", command=lambda:ImageViewer("all")).pack(fill="x", pady=2)
    Button(root, **config, bg="red", text="Back", command=lambda:mainMenu()).pack(fill="x", pady=2)
```

Comment: it should be `command=lambda b=board: PresetSelect(b)`, you need to use a default value

Comment: Please give some more code in order for us to understand what each function is doing